# permantely positioning label regardless of camera view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-3

How would I go about positioning say a sprite or CCButton on a Scene, regardless of the camera view? The issue I'm having is, when I have the character move and the camera follows, elements that I'd like to stay on the screen go off with it as well. Is there an easy way of having these elements stay in the same position, regardless of camera view? Here is what I mean in a visual:

Menu is normally at the top of the screen like so: http://i61.tinypic.com/jsfuy8.png

But when the map is moved, menu is as well!

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have the access to the matrices the general procedure to draw such an overlay is by setting matrices to identity, setting appropriate orthogonal matrix, disabling the depth test and draw the overlay.

Comment: put all the movable nodes onto a layer (just a ccnode) and move that layer node, then add all static nodes to a different layer